# How long before robin no longer needs the nest on my porch?

Tags: zoology, ornithology, ethology, development, life-history

A robin has made a nest on my porch. Unfortunately, the nest is on my weed wacker which I might want to use at some point this summer. Currently, there are two eggs in the nest.

How long will it be before the robin is done needing the nest?

Location is Eastern Massachusetts.

-- *Update May 13* --

I think one of the eggs must have hatched. The robin no longer sits in the nest, she just stands on it constantly.

Comment: As cited in my answer, Cornell University Lab of Ornithology's [All About Birds website](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/) is a trustworthy and excellent website for learning about any bird species across North America (and beyond?). The site contains many pictures and sound clips as well as tons of easy-to-read info about ecology and life histories.

Comment: Go to a crowdfunding site, state your concern for the robin's nest, get the cash to buy another weed wacker, everyone wins. Remember to send pics of the chicks to all the donors. If you associate crowdfunding with begging, tell them you are making a presale of robin chicks' photos. Even get some pro photographer from your region involved. Problem solved, nest saved. Donate any excess cash to WWF or any local wildlife preservation charity if you fancy. Post donation receipt online.

Comment: As a third option, there are professional bird catchers who can move the next without upsetting the mother too much. That would probably cost more than another weed-wacker though.

Comment: @Omegacron I expect the changes of succes to be low.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to Cornell's [All About Birds website](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/American_Robin/lifehistory), you will have to **wait about a month** for the nest to be cleared.

- The egg [**incubation period**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_incubation#Avian_incubation) is 12–14 days.
- Following hatching, the nestlings will remain in the nest for another 13 days (i.e., the **"nestling period" is 13 days**).

However, there are two caveats to this:

- A typical robin clutch size (i.e. the # of eggs in the nest at once) is 3-5 eggs. Since you only have two eggs, that could suggest that more eggs are about to be laid very soon, which may extend the nest occupancy another day or so.
- Some robins use the nest *more than once*!

  > An American Robin can produce three successful broods in one year.

Here's a visual of what the nestling period (approximately) looks like so that you can track your nest visually :) :

[image]

<sup>Source: [*L. Birnbaum*](https://www.learner.org/jnorth/tm/robin/gallery_nestlings.html)</sup>